# Как правильно использовать функцию sum() в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите пожалуйста решение следующей проблемы?
В книге Федорова есть упражнение:

> Напишите программу, которая запрашивает у пользователя две строки и
> формирует из этих строк список. Если строки состоят только из чисел,
> то программа добавляет в середину списка сумму введенных чисел, иначе
> добавляется строка, образованная из слияния двух введенных ранее
> строк. Итоговая строка выводится на экран.

Пытаюсь решить следующим способом:

```
a = input("Введите текст: ")
b = input("Введите текст: ")
c = a + b
list(c)
lst = list(c)
if c.isdigit() == True:
    lst.insert(7, sum(lst))
    print(lst)
```

Здесь начинается проблема, при использовании функции `sum()`, постоянно получается ошибка:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list

Перепробовал несколько вариантов, ничего не помогло. Подскажите пожалуйста, что делаю не так и какой самый простой способ решения?

Comment: `lst.insert(len(lst)//2, sum([ int(i) for i in lst ]))`

Comment: Проблема не в sum(), а в том, что находится в lst. isdigit() сообщает, состоит ли строка только из числовых символов, но НЕ ДЕЛАЕТ строку числом.  ПС. Сравнивать результат isdigit() с True необязательно. ПС. Хороший способ решения проблем, которыми пользовались ещё деды - выводить значения переменных перед использованием и смотреть, действительно ли в них то, что ожидается.